# How to render different components on a page on click of a button without reloading a page in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to click on a menu item on the left, then render a new component on the right. I kinda have a work around for this using `Layout`, but it reloads each time. Is there a way to do this in next.js?

```
export default function MyAccount({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "40px", padding: "50px" }}>
        <Label>
          <Link href={"/"}>Kottage</Link> /{" "}
          <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>My Account</span>
        </Label>
      </div>
      <Stack
        style={{ height: "100%", padding: "0px 50px" }}
        horizontal
        horizontalAlign="center"
      >
        <Sidebar />
        {children}
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}
```

and inside the pages folder, I have this for the individual sub routes

```
export default function index({}: Props) {
  return (
    <MyAccount>
      <Settings />
    </MyAccount>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use a dynamic route+layout "/settings/[setting]" and the "buttons" link to "/settings/my-account", "/settings/my-places" etc.? [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)